# Remove Element of list of tuple when it is ''

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have huge list of tuples that looks like:

```
data =[
    ('-0.167969896634', '0.475981802514', ''), 
    ('-0.186100643368', '0.47510168705', ''), 
    ('-0.205064369305', '0.476225633961', ''),
...]
```

I need to remove the ' ' and convert them all to floats, but I am not sure how to do it. I tried this:

```
[tuple(float(x) for x in t) for t in data]
```

It however will tell me that a `str` cannot be converted to type `float` and I suspect it may be the `''` part?

Comment: Yes, you're getting this error because the empty string `''` can't be properly converted to a float.

Comment: How can I get rid of the ' ' part?

Comment: Just look at the answers

Comment: Does "convert them all to floats" mean you want to convert the `''` to 0.0, or that you want to convert everything _except_ the `''` to floats? You've got answers telling you how to do both of those, because your question is ambiguous.

Comment: Also… are all of your tuples 3 elements, with the last one always an empty string and the first two never? If so, it's probably a lot simpler to just remove the last element than to check the values of all elements. If not… are you sure you want to do this? If some tuples have no blank strings, some have 1, some have 3, you'll end up with a list of tuples of different lengths—which is perfectly legal, but not all that common (usually the position within a tuple means something).

Comment: I commented before I saw the answers. Problem is fixed, either I needed the ' ' to go away or converting them to 0 works. Thanks! The last position is the quality of the laser reflection and I get rid of it in another software. Then these  ' ' started showing up.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert using a try/except block like:

#### Code:

```
def convert(a_float):
    try:
        return float(a_float)
    except ValueError:
        return 0
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = [('-0.167969896634', '0.475981802514', ''),
        ('-0.186100643368', '0.47510168705', ''),
        ('-0.205064369305', '0.476225633961', '')
        ]


new_data = [tuple(convert(f) for f in t) for t in data]
print(new_data)
```

#### Results:

```
[(-0.167969896634, 0.475981802514, 0), 
 (-0.186100643368, 0.47510168705, 0), 
 (-0.205064369305, 0.476225633961, 0)]
```

Comment: This will definitely work for my application! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If empty strings are the only non-numeric values in your floats, then simply filter them out:

```
>>> tuple(map(float, filter(lambda s: s, ('1.23', '3.14', ''))))
(1.23, 3.14)
```

Or simply `None` for identity function:

```
>>> tuple(map(float, filter(None, ('1.23', '3.14', ''))))
(1.23, 3.14)
```

Comment: Change `lambda s: s` to `None`; when `filter` is passed `None`, [it already uses the truthiness of the items directly as if the identity function were passed.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)

Comment: I tried: tuple(map(float, filter(None, data))) and it still said I cannot convert str ' ' to float

Comment: @ColinRunnion it works, see my edited answer. The error should happen at some other place in your code.

Comment: I see! Sorry, my screen seems to not be updating faster than I am responding. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ColinRunnion: Looks like your strings aren't empty, they have spaces in them. Change the `filter` function to `str.strip` instead of `None` and it should work properly.

Answer (score 1):

A simple list comprehension will do the job along with [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map). `filter` will be used to filter out `None` values and `map` will be used to cast the filtered string to `float`

```
>>> [tuple(map(float,filter(None, a))) for a in data]
>>> [
      (-0.167969896634, 0.475981802514), 
      (-0.186100643368, 0.47510168705), 
      (-0.205064369305, 0.476225633961)
    ]
```